# How do I achive to dataWrap only the first image?

Tags: image, background, styles, typo3, typoscript

This snippet...

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap >
tt_content.textpic.stdWrap.innerWrap = <li style="background:url({TSFE:baseUrl}uploads/media/{field:image})">|</li>
tt_content.textpic.stdWrap.innerWrap.insertData = 1
```

...does actually work fine. The result is:

```
<li style="background:url(www.mysite.com/uploads/media/cool.jpg,overlay.png,firstimage.png)">...</li>
```

Well...

> www.mysite.com/uploads/media/  **cool.jpg,  overlay.png,  firstimage.png**

...as you can see above. It actually reads **all**
 available images (3 images in this case) from the content object's media field.
But I want only the **first** image. (which should be image 0, firstimage.png)

Is there a way to achive this with a command like this pseudo code: {field:image:0}, {field:image,1}, {field:image, listNum:1}?

Thank you for your advice. = )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you examine the import function of stdWrap?

http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.5.1/view/1/5/#id2618274

Citing:

> This returns the first image in the field "image" from the data-array:
>
> .import = uploads/pics/
>
> .import.field = image
>
> .import.listNum = 0

You would of course need to change the import folder to uploads/media, and wrap your li tag around the result, but you should get the item you want this way.

Comment: It is not the shortcut that I exspected from Typoscript but the answer is correct.

Comment: Heh.. It tends to get quite wordy, yes, especially when you want to construct multiple strings like you do. Often, I find that it's just as efficient to make a USER object and call a PHP function which returns the concatenated string based on TS parsed data (esp. with multiple languages or workspaces). Alternatively, a well structured COA might do the trick.